# Control image size in Rmd html output

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to import png figure into Rmd/knitr ios_presentation but the standard setting methods don't seem to work as the image size is too big (seems to remain at default 7in). What am I doing wrong ? I read a couple of tutorial pages but they all point to same thing. Tried them - didn't work. Here's my code:

```
---
title: "Title"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen: true
    transition: slower
    fig.width: 4
    fig.caption: true
---

## Slide header

![This is my image](images/image1.png)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a little bit of html like so:

```
<img src="images/image1.png" align="middle" height="450" width="750" margin="0 auto" />
```

Fix the parameters and the alignment to get what you need.